# msdev is not a recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Компилирую код:

> https://github.com/apache/apr

OS Windows 2012 server, запускаю VS2012 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt.

Указываю команду как указано в документации:

```
nmake -f Makefile.win
```

Выдает что нету **msdev**

```
msdev is not a recognized as an internal or external command
```

не нашел где есть **msdev**.

Answer (score 1):

Как пишут вот [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34ce6859-e876-4af9-8d16-0ac5c41df2e4/how-do-i-get-msdevexe?forum=Vsexpressvc), `msdev.exe` - это имя исполняемого файла IDE VC6, а  начиная с VS2003 файл называется `devenv.exe` (или `VCExpress.exe` в экспресс версиях).

Кстати, если открыть [Makefile.win](https://github.com/apache/apr/blob/trunk/Makefile.win#L10), то можно обнаружить там вот такие комментарии:

```
# You can override the build mechanism, choose only one;
#
#     USEMAK=1 - compile from exported make files
#     USEDSW=1 - compile from .dsw / .dsp VC6 projects
#     USESLN=1 - compile from converted .sln / .vcproj VC7+ files
```

а далее, идёт автоматическое определение, какую билд-систему использовать. И судя по тому, что в репо apr присутствуют файлы `apr.dsw` и `apr.dsp`, по-умолчанию предполагается, что сборка будет производиться в **VC6**.